# Why does it loop twice?

Tags: loop

I have this loop and I don't know why, I have a "load more" button and when I click on it, it loads all articles a second time.

Can someone help ?

```
<div class="content">
<div class="container load_more">
  <div class="row">

  <?php

  $args = array('category_name' => 'actu, quizz' );
  $the_query = new WP_Query ($args);?>
  <?php
  if($the_query->have_posts()):
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="le_post_entier ">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('actus'); ?></a>
      <div class="col-md-12 postbody ">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </div>
        <a class="cta" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">DÉCOUVRIR &#8594;</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  <?php  endwhile; ;endif;
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** I've closed the tags but it still loop twice

Comment: Where is the code for the load more button?

Comment: Hello, it's a plugin called WP Load More Posts

Comment: Have you asked the person who created the plugin? We don't know how that plugin works.

Comment: I use it on an other page of my site and it doesn't load twice

Comment: Maybe it's just a closing tag problem? reading the code you posted, there's a closing <a> tag missing. `<div class="col-md-12 postbody "><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>`

Comment: Your query doesn't specify what page of results you want returned, so it will always return the first page. But again, we don't know how that plugin works, so I can't say how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Takebo it's problem with  tag.

`<div class="col-md-12 postbody ">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>`

**here is missing `</a>`**

```
    `</div>
    <a class="cta" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">DÉCOUVRIR &#8594;</a>
  </div>
</div>`
```